# Python folium package for 'satellite' map

Tags: python, satellite, folium

I am trying to have a zoomable satellite map for my Transportation network analysis. Other free maps all OK but could not get satellite to work. I am using:

```
token = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiYXNhZGkxOTc4IiwiYSI6ImNqanphbHVhMDA4ODgzd25yYzY1MW1nc2oifQ.dDDcWq2-tUC-XXXXXXX'
tiletxt = 'https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.satellite/3/2/3@2x.png?access_token=' + str(token)

my_map = folium.Map(location = [lat,lon], tiles = tiletxt, attr='WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE?', zoom_start = 7)
```

But give a grid static map which cannot be zoomed etc.

Can I get some instructions how I can get a nice satellite map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is almost correct. Fixed one:

```
token = "pk...." # your mapbox token
tileurl = 'https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.satellite/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x.png?access_token=' + str(token)

m = folium.Map(
    location=[48.73596, 11.18434], zoom_start=9, tiles=tileurl, attr='Mapbox')
```

Answer (score 10):

You can also use `ESRI Satellite` for satellite images.  I used this:

```
tile = folium.TileLayer(
        tiles = 'https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
        attr = 'Esri',
        name = 'Esri Satellite',
        overlay = False,
        control = True
       ).add_to(map_1)
```